# how do i keep text from desappearing from tkinter GUI when restarting the program?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a Text box with a line of "User ID", "User Name" and "Phone Number". I get those data with Entry widgets.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Program')  
root.geometry('1350x750')


#get User ID
entry_id_user = Entry(root, font=('arial', 12, 'bold'))
entry_id_user.pack()

#get User Name
entry_user_name= Entry(root, font=('arial', 12, 'bold'))
entry_user_name.pack()

#get Phone Number
entry_phone = Entry(root, font=('arial', 12, 'bold'))
entry_phone.pack()

#create text box where I'll print the data I got from the Entry widgets
text_box = Text(root)
text_box.pack()

#function to get the data and print them in the text_box
def print_text():
    text_box.insert(END, '\t\t'+ entry_id_user.get()+
                         '\t\t' + entry_user_name.get()+
                         '\t\t' + entry_phone.get() + '\n')
#button to print data    
button_text_box = Button(root, text='Ok', command=print_text)
button_text_box.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

problem is, whenever I close the app all written data inside the text_box resets and disappears. How can I keep the texts there, for viewing even after restarting the app? What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the text in the Text widget to a file and reload it. In your case, you could simply store the data in the text widget to a txt file and reload it when necessary.

Here is an example.

```py
from tkinter import *


def save():

    with open('save.txt', 'w') as f:
      f.write(text_box.get('1.0', 'end'))


def load():
    text_box.delete('1.0', 'end')
    with open('save.txt', 'r') as f:
        data = f.read()

    text_box.insert('end', data)
    

root = Tk()
root.title('Program')  

...

Button(root, text='save', command=save).pack()
Button(root, text='load', command=load).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

But for what you are trying to achieve you should be using Treeview.

In the below example I'll be showing you how to save and load data from Treeview to a json file.

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import json



def save():
    dict_save = {'user id': [], 'user name': [], 'phone no': []}

    for iid in tree_view.get_children():
        for value, key in zip(tree_view.item(iid)['values'], dict_save.keys()):
            dict_save[key].append(value)
           
    
    print(dict_save)
    with open('save.json', 'w') as f:
      json.dump(dict_save, f)


def load():
    with open('save.json', 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    tree_view.delete(*tree_view.get_children())

    for value in zip(*data.values()):
        tree_view.insert('', 'end', values=value)
    

root = Tk()
root.title('Program')  

...

tree_view = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=(0, 1, 2), show='headings', selectmode='browse')
tree_view.pack()


for index, x in enumerate(['user id', 'user name', 'phone no']):
    tree_view.heading(index, text=x)
    tree_view.column(index, anchor='center')


#function to insert into list view
def print_text():
    tree_view.insert('', 'end', values=(entry_id_user.get(), entry_user_name.get(), entry_phone.get()))
        
...    

Button(root, text='save', command=save).pack()
Button(root, text='load', command=load).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't know what you did, but it worked. Allow me to assemble your code into my program. Thanks!

Comment: @Moon All I did was to save the data into a file. Once your program is closed the memory is deallocated hence it is necessary to save the data from your memory to disk. Your GUI object state won't be saved hence, requiring you to write your own methods to save what is necessary to restore the previous state of the program. You, also might want to look at pickling in python.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the user id etc in variables such as

```
user_id = entry_id_user.get()
```

etc. and when the app closes and restart you can get values by using variables user_id.